# Change tab spec intent of Tab Host dynamically

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabactivity

I am having a tabhost with 3 tabs. Based on some value obtained I want to change the intent of one of the tab spec in tab host programatically.

Is there any way of doing this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this.

```
public class TabGroup1 extends TabGroupActivity{

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  if(vlaue1)
   {
        startChildActivity("Home_Activity", new Intent(this,Activity_A.class));
    }
    else
   {
       startChildActivity("Home_Activity", new Intent(this,Activity_B.class));}
     }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to change the intent of the same tab. For example if initially I am loading Activity A on click on second tab. After getting some value I want to show Activity B instead of Activity A on selection of the same tab. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: hi i change the answer Please see.

Comment: Hi Pankaj, I am using Tab Activity and even tried this in the child activity. But the onCreate() method of the child activity is not being called while switching tabs. Is there any other way possible ?

Comment: can you Please post your Code ?

Comment: My code looks similar to the one in the link: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/